# Indent preprocessor directives as C code in emacs

Tags: c, emacs, coding-style, indentation

Emacs, by default, does not indent pre-processor code. I know it has historical roots that are obsolete by now.

However, having a code with a lot of #ifdef unindented is hard to read.

So I would like to make emacs automatic indentation give me something like that:

```
void myfunc() {
    int foo;

    #ifdef BAR
    printf(foo);
    #endif

    return foo;
}
```

Instead of what I get now :

```
void myfunc() {
    int foo;

#ifdef BAR
    printf(foo);
#endif

    return foo;
}
```

Any leads on that issue you emacs hackers :) ?

Comment: Pretending that preprocessor macros have block scope is a serious mistake.  It does take several dozen missing feet to discover this by yourself.

Comment: +1 to @Hans.  The second form is actually much clearer IMO.  Since you are actually altering the content of the file, it seems much more sensible to indent at the file "scope" level (i.e. no indent at all).  I'm not sure how valid it is to talk about scope with respect to preprocessor directives.

Comment: If you care how your preprocessor code is indented, it means you have **way too much** of it. `#ifdef` never belongs in actual source files; this is the bane of unreadable legacy code like GNU `screen`. Instead of per-system tweaks, write portable code to begin with and hide the conditionals to fix broken systems in a header file somewhere. Or if it's for optional features, do similar, and have the macros/function calls for that functionality expand to `0` or `(void)0` when the feature is disabled.

Comment: I get your point, and I'm not telling you're wrong. However, in my case, I do code instrumentation, and the use of preprocessor directives is the best compromise I found to enable to compile a normal version or an instrumented one... But it makes the code unreadable with the default indentation.

Comment: I'm with Jocelyn on this one. For me, openmp pragmas are the deciding factor. Having those "outdented" really disrupts the flow of the code. I could see a compromise if it were possible to [only indent pragmas but leave if, etc., outdented](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265205/indent-openmp-directives-as-c-c-code-in-emacs). But apparently that's not possible.

Comment: I'll also back Jocelyn point here.  I agree that there should be the absolute minimum use of C preprocessor logic in source code and agree with using replacement techniques instead.  However, lots of embedded code does use a lot and some even break the code scopes.  Of course it's important to know that the indentation of *any* C/C++ code has nothing to do with the scope and it's important to realize it with C preprocessor. But indentation of C preprocessor in code that use it extensively does help seeing the logic flow.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can simply tell Emacs to add an offset to the pre-processor lines.

- Put the cursor (`point`) in a pre-processor line
- then press <kbd>C-c C-o</kbd> (control-c control-o)
- the minibuffer should say `Syntactic symbol to change:`,
- type `cpp-macro`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Enter the new offset (number - usually `0`)

Then a <kbd>TAB</kbd> on each pre-processor line should indent it correctly. (or <kbd>M-x</kbd>`indent-region` ...).

To have the change set permanently, you can for instance add the required lines in your `.emacs` file.
An easy way to copy a previously entered command is <kbd>c-x ESC ESC</kbd> and use the arrow keys to find the `(c-set-offset ...)` Elisp command.

That should be

```
(c-set-offset (quote cpp-macro) 0 nil)
```

Comment: Actually, That's the way, but to obtain the behaviour I want, I need to set the offset to 0, not 3.