# Indent openmp directives as C/C++ code in emacs

Tags: c, emacs, openmp

In a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669219/indent-preprocessor-directives-as-c-code-in-emacs), I learned how to indent macros as regular C code on emacs. I just need this because of `#pragma omp` directives from OpenMP, but I'd like to maintain all other kind of macros, like `#if` and `#endif`, indented as the default.

```
(c-set-offset (quote cpp-macro) 0 nil)
```

The rule above treats all macros as the same. My question is: Is there a way to specialize this rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at `M-x describe-variable c-offsets-alist`, which defines a list of variables that represent the syntactic constructs of the various programming languages, you'd only see `cpp-macro` and `cpp-macro-cont` which represent macros and continuing macros respectively.  The list does not tell between `#pragma` and say, `#if`.

So, there is no direct way that Emacs provides to tell `#pragma` from other directives.